# Set a breakpoint that stops the code whenever a variable matches a given value, in XCode

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

In the following minimal code

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass{
    
public:
    
    bool x;
    
    void MyFunction();  
    
};

void MyClass::MyFunction(void){
    
    std::cout << "You just called MyFunction\n";
    
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    MyClass my_class;
    my_class.MyFunction();

    return 0;
    
}
```

I would like, in XCode, to stop the code with a breakpoint or watchpoint whenever the variable `x` of MyClass equals `true`. I have tried with watchpoints and symbolic breakpoints, but nothing works.

Do you know how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional breakpoint.

Set a breakpoint on a line of code in Xcode's editor. Select the breakpoint, right-click, and choose Edit Breakpoint.

A popover opens. Enter the condition in the Condition text field.

Comment: This is not going to work. The condition cannot single out cases where the variables changed its value.

Comment: In your question you said you wanted the breakpoint to fire when `x` is true. That's what a conditional breakpoint does. If you set the condition for the breakpoint to `x` being true, what happens? Does the breakpoint fire every time `x` becomes true? In your comment you talk about variables changing value. That's what watchpoints are for. If conditional breakpoints and watchpoints aren't working, you're going to have edit your question and provide more detailed information about " I have tried with watchpoints and symbolic breakpoints, but nothing works." to get a good answer.